# Prometheus+grafana: How to graph events per time slot

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I have been struggling to have a graph in grafana which shows number of events per x units of time, like 1min,5min, 30secs etc. Just to give an idea what I am looking for, please see following image:

[image]

I want to have a graph which shows time slots(like for 5 min slots, 5.30-5.35, 5.35-5.40, so on....) on X axis and Y axis shows events per time slot.

I have configured a counter and I can use prometheus's increase function to find delta of events over a period of time(say 1m) as:

increase(mycounter[1m])

But the graph generated is not like what I want. It gives more of an average of the increase over time windows, not the exact increase in each of the time window.

Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will never get the exact increase in each of the time windows due to the way Prometheus `rate` and `increase` work.

By setting the `min step` in Grafana to whatever window step you like and the range selection in the query itself to `$__interval` and `$__rate_interval` once Grafana 7.2 is released, you get pretty close to what you want. But consider that once you zoom out far enough the window will start to grow if there are not enough pixels to fit all "windows". In addition having the min step and range exactly the same can and will lead to increases getting lost. `$__rate_interval` fixes that.

Edit:

The queries from Grafana to Prometheus contains a step parameter that Prometheus "steps through" along the given time range. For every step the respective query, for example `rate(counter_total[5m])` is evaluated. The min step is a lower bound for Grafana. There are several other locations where you can define something similar. For example in your data source settings where you set your scrape interval.

The actual step value that is used in the end is calculated based on a number of other factors. For example the number of pixels available. But you can also fix the number of total steps you want, for example to 10. Here is where `$__interval` comes in. It basically synchronizes the step with the rate range and ensures that you have always the highest possible resolution while preventing under- and overfetching. Disadvantages: Graph may become quite spiky and noisy and you might prefer the look of a 5/10/15m rate. In addition, you can lose increases in your data if your rate range is exactly the same as the step. But the same is true with a fixed rate range and a big enough time range. `$__rate_interval` fixes that by always adding the scrape interval to the range selector.

Again, I recommend watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09bR9kJczKM

Comment: Can you explain how exactly min step works internally? And where actually $__internal picks its value from?

Comment: If you have the time I recommend this video / webcast from GrafanaCONline 2020. It explains it pretty well. I will add a bit to my answer as well